# Rails app does not sort publications by year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails 5 app with publications. These publications need to be ordered by year, with recent years on top.

The years field on a publication has the integer datatype.

The PublicationsController has a sort actionmethod:

```
def sort
  @category = PublicationCategory.find_by_name(params[:category])
  @publications = Publication.sort_by_category(@category.id).grouped_by_year
end
```

I created a scope grouped_by_year:

```
app/models/publication.rb

scope :grouped_by_year, ->{ order(year: :desc).group_by { |p| p.year} }
```

I created three publications, one of the year 2016, 2015 and 2014

but instead of appearing in this order:

```
2016
2015
2014
```

they appear in the order:

```
2015
2014
2016
```

Does someone have a idea what the problem could be?

My code repository is at:

https://github.com/acandael/hedera-rails

thanks for your help,

Anthony

Comment: Can you try `scope :grouped_by_year, ->{ group(:year).order(year: :desc) }` ?

Comment: I tried it, but then I get the error: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "publications.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ..._id" = $1 GROUP BY "publications"."year" ORDER BY created_at...

Comment: I see that somehow it is ordering by `created_at`, so first of all, can you rename the column `year` in `publication` to something else since I think that is a **reserved word** and then try again ?

Comment: `year` is not a reserved word in postgres

Comment: I renamed the column to publication_year, and then I tried: scope :grouped_by_year, ->{ group(:publication_year).order(publication_year: :desc) } but I still get the error: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "publications.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...OUP BY "publications"."publication_year" ORDER BY created_at...

Comment: Have you tried removing `.order('created_at desc')` from the `sort_by_category`scope?

Comment: Hi Iceman, thanks a lot, I removed .order('created_at desc') from the sort_by_category scope, and now the publication years are ordered in the right order!

Comment: Good, I made an answer since this worked out for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this from the `sort_by_category` scope, it's messing up the ordering of your final query.

```
.order('created_at desc')
```